# Transform part of an identification number into text VBA access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Can someone help me with a little problem. In summary I have a db where you input someones personal details and I have 4 fields I would like VBA to generate automatically. First field is an ID Number field then following that is DateOfBirth and Age fields. They are auto generated from just the ID field. However, to save me time, I want a part of the ID number field to generate whether a person is male or female.

To explain this let me set an example. The ID number is based on South African identification number. It's a 13 digit number e.g. 851205 5205 08 6. The first 6 numbers tells the date of birth (1985/12/05). That part of the number updates my DOB field and then also tells me the persons age with more VBA. Now i want the numbers "5205" to auto generate my gender field whether a person is male or female. Females are assigned numbers in the range 0000-4999 and males from 5000-9999. If you like more detail then please Google 'decoding your South African ID Number'.

So if i should type in that ID number above then it will define the person as a male. Can anyone help me with some VBA?

Thank you

found a solution and it works just the way i want it to:

```
If (Mid([txtIDnumber].Value, 7, 4) > 4999) Then
Me.cboGender = "MALE"
Else
Me.cboGender = "FEMALE"
End If
```

Comment: This ID includes the spaces shown in example? I assume you are using string manipulation functions to extract the date part so do more of the same for the gender. `IIf(Mid([ID],8,1)>=5,"M","F")`. Should not save Age in table, calculate this value in queries when needed.

Comment: @June7 my IDNumber field code on after update is as follows and yes theres no spaces. was using spaces to give in detail description.
'Dim strDoB As String
Dim dtmDoB As Date

 With Me.ActiveControl
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            strDoB = Left(.Value, 6)
         dtmDoB = DateSerial(Left(strDoB, 2), _
                              Mid(strDoB, 3, 2), _
                               Mid(strDoB, 5, 2))
            dtmDoB = DateAdd("yyyy", IIf(dtmDoB > VBA.Date, -100, 0), dtmDoB)
            Me.txtDOB = dtmDoB
        Else
           Me.txtDOB = Null
        End If'

Comment: sorry my coding looks a little messed up in the reply

Comment: Instead of a comment, edit your question.